# For which $z_{1}, z_{2} \in \mathbb{C} $ $Re(z_{1}z_{2}) = Re(z_{1})Re(z_{2})$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

We know that $Re(z_{1}z_{2}) = Re(z_{1})Re(z_{2}) - Im(z_{1})Im(z_{2})$ where $z_{1} = x_{1} + iy_{1}$ and
$z_{2} = x_{2} + iy_{2}$

if $y_{1}\times y_{2} = 0$ we got $Re(z_{1}z_{2}) = Re(z_{1})Re(z_{2})$ 
but are there any other constraints on $z_{1}, z_{2}$ such as $Re(z_{1}z_{2}) = Re(z_{1})Re(z_{2})$?

Comment: You essentially answered your own question. Do you see that?

Answer (score 1):

There are no other conditions. If $y_1$ and $y_2$ are non-zero, it is easy to see the equality does not hold. The implication $y_1y_2=0\implies\operatorname{Re}(z_1z_2)=\operatorname{Re}(z_1)\operatorname{Re}(z_2)$ is also true in the other direction.